# Switch screens in bottombar flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a bottom bar that is supposed to switch between screens when selected but I do not know how to make that work. I know is all contained in the buildpages() widget. Can you guide me through?

```
Widget buildBottomBar() {
    final style = TextStyle(color: Colors.white);
    return BottomNavigationBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
      selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
      unselectedItemColor: Colors.black,
      showSelectedLabels: true,
      showUnselectedLabels: false,
      selectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
      currentIndex: index,
      items: [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Text('App', style: style),
          label: 'Idioms List',
          activeIcon: Icon(Icons.list)
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Text('FAVORITES', style: style),
          label: 'Favorited',
          activeIcon: Icon(Icons.favorite_border_rounded)
        ),
      ],
      onTap: (int index) => setState(() => this.index = index),
    );
  }
    Widget buildPages() {
      switch (index) {
        case 0:
          return FavoriteScreen();
        case 1:
          return MainPage();
        default:
          return Container();
      }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create a page for bottom nav bar and
give stful widget then create a list of page like this

```
      static const List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    YorPageclass1(),
   YourPageclass2(), etc...];
```

and create a function for Ontap like

```
void _onItemTapped(int index) {
setState(() {
  _selectedIndex = index;
});}
```

and create a scaffold widget for pages

```
      @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('BottomNavigationBar Sample'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.business),
            label: 'Business',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.school),
            label: 'School',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
```

}

Comment: where do _selectedIndex is coming from? Where should I define that?

Comment: just upper in @ovverride